# How to update the value of elements in an array with many objects with same keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native

I am working on a react native app, i have a carousal which currently has static data, data is in an array in a file entry.js,
I want to make the carousal dynamic,
I want to update the value for title,subtitle,illustration of each objects in the array, after parsing json data from API in HomeScreen.js file.

Entry.js

```
export const ENTRIES1 = [
{
    title: 'Beautiful and dramatic Antelope Canyon',
    subtitle: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et nuncat mergitur',
    illustration: 'http://i.imgur.com/UYiroysl.jpg'
},
{
    title: 'Earlier this morning, NYC',
    subtitle: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    illustration: 'http://i.imgur.com/UPrs1EWl.jpg'
},
{
    title: 'White Pocket Sunset',
    subtitle: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et nuncat ',
    illustration: 'http://i.imgur.com/MABUbpDl.jpg'
},
{
    title: 'Acrocorinth, Greece',
    subtitle: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et nuncat mergitur',
    illustration: 'http://i.imgur.com/KZsmUi2l.jpg'
},
{
    title: 'The lone tree, majestic landscape of New Zealand',
    subtitle: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    illustration: 'http://i.imgur.com/2nCt3Sbl.jpg'
},
{
    title: 'Middle Earth, Germany',
    subtitle: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    illustration: 'http://i.imgur.com/lceHsT6l.jpg'
}];
```

This is where i want to parse the data and update the array.

HomeScreen.js

```
import { ENTRIES1, ENTRIES2 } from './static/entries';
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
componentDidMount() {
return fetch('http://api.com/api/get_posts')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    try {

    }   catch (error) {
        // Error saving data
    }           
    this.setState({


    }, function() {
      // do something with new state
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
}
```

The API structure is like this:

```
{
 "status": "ok",
 "count": 8,
 "posts": [
  {
  "title": 76964,
  "subtitle": "post",
  "illustration": "modi-shinzo-abe-go-roadshow-gujarat"
  },
  {
  "title": 76964,
  "subtitle": "post",
  "illustration": "modi-shinzo-abe-go-roadshow-gujarat"
  },
  {
  "title": 76964,
  "subtitle": "post",
  "illustration": "modi-shinzo-abe-go-roadshow-gujarat"
  }
  ]
  }
```

I want the posts array in api to be parsed and updated in array ENTRIES1 in the Entry.js file.

Comment: You can't change the contents of `Entry.js`, but I assume you're using the array `ENTRIES1` as inital value for your `state.entries`, right? So all you need to do is `this.setState({ entries: response.posts });`

Comment: actually i am using it this way without initial state, this is how it was in carousal docs
 <Carousel
     autoplay={true}
     removeClippedSubviews={false}
     >
         { this.getSlides(ENTRIES1) }
     </Carousel>
    getSlides (entries) {
        if (!entries) {
            return false;
        }
        return entries.map((entry, index) => {
            return (
                <SliderEntry
                  key={`carousel-entry-${index}`}
                  even={(index + 1) % 2 === 0}
                  {...entry}
                />
            );
        });
    }

Comment: Just use `this.getSlides(this.state.entries)` instead and initialize `state.entries` to `ENTRIES1`.

Comment: Note that I'm not just suggesting to do it that way on a whim; initializing `state`, then changing it during the course of the app (which is what triggers a call to `render()`!) is the fundamental mechanism on which the react framework is built.